# meilleurs d'opportunités ou meilleures opportunités?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

The following sentences would be correct?

> -Elle a eu une vide plus moderne avec meilleurs d'opportunités.
>
> -Et nous pourrons de bavarder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences contain mistakes. I think this is what you meant to say:

> Elle a eu une vie ("life", "vide" means "void") plus moderne avec de meilleures opportunités. ("meilleures" being the adjective applied to the name "opportunités").
>
> Et nous pourrons bavarder. (the verb "pouvoir" should not be followed by "de" when followed by an infinitive verb).

Comment: Cool! Thanks! And which verbs are followed then by "de" when followed by an infinitive verb?

Comment: As far as I know (I'm a native French speaker) there is no specific rule but there are a number of verbs I can provide that follow this principle (though it is probably not exhaustive): oublier, rêver, essayer, accepter, conseiller, choisir, permettre, interdire...

Answer (score 0):

Ni l'une ni l'autre des deux phrases n'est correcte;

correct :

> Elle a eu un vide plus moderne avec de meilleures opportunités.
>   Et nous pourront bavarder. (*Les phrases commençant par « et » ne sont cependant pas recommandées dans la grammaire traditionnelle française.*)